# I can't get "apt-get install php5-suhosin" to work

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, php

I am running ubuntu 13.04. I cannot get my php website to work because I cannot install
php5-suhosin.

It said this each time that I have tried `apt-get install php5-suhosin`:

```
Package php5-suhosin is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

I've already done `apt-get update`
`and apt-get upgrade`.

I also cannot seem to install it with compiling either. Please help! Thank you!

**^^OUTDATED^^  New problem below!**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
php5-suhosin : Depends: phpapi-20090626
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: have you looked [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/php5-suhosin)?

Comment: @mrseed Already tried. It does nothing.

Comment: Check this <http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/php5-suhosin>

Comment: @Ahmadgeo That's the same thing that mrseed said. :/

Comment: @user160879 Sorry for the dublicate link... What I meant actually is to manually download the packages you want and install them instead of using apt-get install command

Comment: @Ahmadgeo Oh. :P I'm little new to this stuff so could you explain the process of manually downloading and installing a package?

Comment: @user160879 Do you have the universe repository enabled ? See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I do now. It almost worked. New error: "The following packages have unmet dependencies:
php5-suhosin : Depends: phpapi-20090626
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."

Comment: @user160879 me too :) actually I have noidea about the php package you are talking about, but this is a method I usually use when encountering such issues (manually download the required package as .deb file, then run the command sudo dpkg --install package.deb) and it works every time.

Comment: @user160879 as for missing dependencies; you may run (sudo apt-get -F install) to fix it for you.

Answer (score 9):

Suhosin for PHP 5.4+ has never been finished by upstream developer in time for Debian/Ubuntu release and thus the php5-suhosin package has been dropped from Debian (and Ubuntu).

Just remove the leftovers and forget about php5-suhosin.

You don't need php5-suhosin to run the website(s) in php.

**EDIT**: The suhosin.org has made a new release supporting PHP5.4+ after several years of inactivity.  If you really think you cannot live without it, you can compile suhosin extension yourself from source.

Comment: Then why doesn't my sites php scripts work?

Comment: Then you are asking a wrong question.  If your question is really about a non-working PHP, you should close this as answered (because honestly this answers your questions) and post a new question with more details about your PHP setup (packages installed, etc...).